# Discord JDA. Как удалять сообщения в Discord?

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: нужно удалить `N` сообщений на канале в дискорде. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данная проблема частая и выход в ней не всегда очевиден.

Пообщавшись с разработчиками, они предлогают использовать `purgeMessages`. С данным методом я еще лично не разобрался до конца, но знаю разные вариант удаления сообщений.

Примеры ниже **показывают удаление всей истории сообщений** на канале. Удаление `N` сообщений будет основана на данных примерах кода:

### 1 вариант

Данный вариант является самым примитивным (и где-то надежным):

```java
for (Message mes : event.getChannel().getIterableHistory()) {
    try {
           event.getChannel().deleteMessageById(mes.getId()).queue();
   } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

> Плюсы:
>
> - Работал с этой функцией полгода - ни разу не подвела
> - Удаляет сообщения отправленые в любой период времени
>
> Минусы:
>
> - Удаляет **1.5-2 сообщения в секунду**... Не трудно посчитать, что длинная история сообщений будет удаляться долго.
> - Не особо приветствуется разрабами.

### 2 Вариант:

Данный вариант является немного продвинутым и его можно часто увидеть на просторах Youtube-уроков по Discord JDA, но у него **есть огромные НО**:

```java
event.getChannel().getHistory().retrievePast(100).queue(
   m -> data.getGuild()
       .getTextChannelById(event.getChannel().getId())
       .deleteMessages(m).queue()
);
```

> Плюсы:
>
> - Быстро удаляет сообщения
> - Предыдущий пункт был первым и последним плюсом
>
> Минусы:
>
> - Максимально можно удалить за раз 100 сообщений
> - Нельзя удалять сообщения, которые превышают 2 недельной давности (даже если оно из 99 всретится 100 - Discord не позволит его удалить)

### 3 Вариант

Данный вариант еще не обкатан мною, но совмещает в себе плюсы двух предыдущих вариантов:

*P.S. честно, я ничего не  понял в этом коде, но знаю одно - оно удаляет достаточно быстро 500 сообщений.*

```java
event.getChannel().getIterableHistory().takeAsync(500).thenAccept(event.getChannel()::purgeMessages);
```

> Плюсы:
>
> - Удаляет сообщений любой давности (проверено на 3+ месячных сообщениях)
> - Удаляет быстро сообщения друг за другом (3-6 сообщений в секунду, но могу ошибаться)
> - Мало кода. В одну строчку как-никак)
> - Даже если у вас на канале сообщений 10, а вы пытаетесь удалить 500 - программа это выполнит без труда)
>
> Минусы:
>
> - "I'd better delete the whole channel and create a copy of it" (Перевод: "Лучше удалить целый канал и создать копию его") (c) Один из
>   разрабов
> - Фиксированное  кол-во сообщений (надо писать сколько хочешь удалить сообещний... Способ нахождения длины всей истории переписок еще не
>   нашел.)
> - Может работать не стабильно.